# Extract XML from XMLType notated Java class

Tags: java, xml

I have a Java class which is annotated as a XMLType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "fooClass", propOrder = {
    "fooElement1",
    "fooElement2"
})
public class fooClass{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String fooElement1;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String fooElement2;

    .....

}
```

I want to be able to extract the XML representation (preferably as stream but a String would be OK as well) in Java, something along the lines of:

```
fooClass foo = new fooClass()
foo.setFooElement1("baba")
foo.setFooElement2("abab")

String xmlRep = DomSomething(foo)
```

Any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably create a JAXB context, see this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(fooClass.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fooInstance, ps);

    String result = new String(baos.toByteArray());

    ...
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Creating a JAXB context can be expensive, you probably don't want to do that on every call...

Comment: I already have JAXB content created previously so it might be worth it

Comment: This doesn't work since fooClass has no XMLRootElement and I can't add one, any other ideas?

Comment: @jonatzin Just stumbled across this, hopefully this will help you to set up JAXB without annotations... http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html - but maybe this isn't that helpful